# how to set constraint to different view if certain view visibility is gone in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have two different toolbars in my main activity. I only show one toolbar at a time. if one toolbar visibility is visible, the other will be gone. it is controlled by if else statement

the two toolbar is called:

- general toolbar
- search toolbar

those two have different height.

I am using `include` to attach the toolbar in my main activity.

here is the xml of my main activity

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity" android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_main_activity">


    <include
            android:id="@+id/include_toolbar_general"
            layout="@layout/include_toolbar_general"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <include
            android:id="@+id/include_toolbar_search"
            layout="@layout/include_toolbar_search"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_toolbar_general"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

as you can see, `include_toolbar_general` is initially visible. and the fragment below it has constraintTop_toBottomOf to `include_toolbar_general`

the problem is, when in certain condition, the `include_toolbar_general` will be gone. and the fragment will go up and it seems overlap the `include_toolbar_search` (that visible, if general toolbar is gone).

i want to make,   when `include_toolbar_general` visibility is gone, then the fragment below it will have constraintTop_toBottomOf `include_toolbar_search`

how to do that ?

Comment: The easiest way would be moving both of **<include>** - includes in same layout. Meaning you can wrap both of includes inside <FrameLayout> and afterwards you make dependant constraint for "nav_host_fragment" to **app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set a `Barrier` to be aligned with the bottom of whichever toolbar is currently showing and constrain the top of the `Fragment` to that `Barrier`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="include_toolbar_general,include_toolbar_search" />
```

And in your `<fragment>` change:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_toolbar_general"
```

to:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
```

Comment: This approach is working in case the toolbars are overlapped.

Answer (score 4):

In your design, you have two toolbars only one of which is visible at any given time; the other is `gone`. A fragment below the toolbar should be be constrained to the bottom of the toolbar that is showing. Here is one way to do this without introducing additional complexity or views. Take a look at [Visibility Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#VisibilityBehavior) in the documentation for reference.

Below is a layout that mimics your layout with *TextViews* instead of includes for simplicity, but the concepts will work for your included files. Each *TextView* has its top constrained to the view above.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/include_toolbar_general"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="include_toolbar_general"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/include_toolbar_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="include_toolbar_search"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include_toolbar_general" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="nav_host_fragment"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_toolbar_search" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the following video, the *TextViews* that represent your included layout are alternated set to `gone`. As you can see, the fragment responds by setting its top to the bottom of the view that is visible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @PawelLaskowski. Several ways to do this. Questions tend to be simplified (thankfully!), so one never knows what else about a design that is not revealed that prompts the OP to prefer one answer over another.

Comment: This is a very good solution for view stacking in cases like these. But for a case where two views are superposed, and both require constraints from another view, then only a barrier would work as per Pawel's solution. In order to keep margins and constraints consistent, a barrier is best used to interchange visibility of the views.